# Angular JS - What is '$scope' and how does it compare to using the 'this' keyword?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am new to Angular JS and have been taught it the 'this' way:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('Comment',[]);
    app.controller('CommentCtrl',function(){
        this.welcome = 'Hello!';
    });
</script>
<p ng-app='Comment' ng-controller='CommentCtrl as ctrl'>
    Angular says: {{ ctrl.welcome }}
</p>
```

Which shows 'Angular says: Hello!' inside the paragraph.

However, every angular application I have ever seen has used '$scope' instead of 'this', like I was taught.

Could someone please explain a few of the pros and cons of each, and what exactly $scope is in terms that I can understand?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with my question? It took a lot of effort to get my reputation. Please don't just take it off me.

Comment: The "controller as" functionality is a fairly recent addition to angularjs hence the reason that most tutorials use $scope.  I have a read a few articles that suggest the angularjs 2.0 will not use $scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some Good Points**:

- `this`

  - When the controller constructor function is called, `this` is the controller.
  - When a function defined on a $scope object is called, `this` is the "scope in effect when the function was called".  This may (or may not!) be the $scope that the function is defined on.  So, inside the function, `this` and $scope may **not** be the same.
- $scope

  - Every controller has an associated $scope object.
  - A controller (constructor) function is responsible for setting model properties and functions/behavior on its associated $scope.
  - Only methods defined on this $scope object (and parent scope objects, if prototypical inheritance is in play) are accessible from the HTML/view.  E.g., from ng-click, filters, etc.

[Here is cool article by Todd Motto](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)

Happy Helping!